# Creating a nested ListView in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a `ListView` that will represent a menu with sub menus which in turn will have theirs, etc. The menus will be generated from a database table that has a recursive relationship.

How do I bind the `IEnumerable` that I retrieve from the database, so that the listview generates other listviews within itself to represent the sub menus ?

Also, what should I add to the template to make it 'display itself' in a child?